# After upgrade to TeX Live 2018: xcolor's table option interferes with vertical spacing in tabular environment

Tags: color, texlive, tabularx, texlive-2017, texlive-2018

I upgraded from TeX Live 2017 to 2018 (on a Mac) and realized something strange (?). Previously the following showed lines with increasing spaces, now that seems to be ignored and the behavior is as if only `\\` was used. It's fine, though, if I omit the `table` option of `xcolor`. Any idea why/what happens?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  1\\[2mm]
  2\\[4mm]
  3\\[8mm]
  4\\[16mm]
  5\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

Compiling with `pdflatex MWE.tex` and `\listfiles` in the preamble, this is the output I obtain:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty)
No file MWE.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./MWE.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2018/04/07 v2.4g Tabular extension package (FMi)
tabularx.sty    2016/02/03 v2.11b `tabularx' package (DPC)
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********

 )</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on MWE.pdf (1 page, 9681 bytes).
Transcript written on MWE.log.
```

Comment: Works fine for me with TL2018. How are you compiling? pdflatex?

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. Yes, `pdflatex MWE.tex` (same with `texi2dvi -p`. I still see the problem. `pdfTeX` version `Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19` (also still the same with standard `article`)

Comment: Can you place `\listfiles` in your preamble and copy and past it's output from the log file to your question?

Comment: This is what I get from your code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Oyy.png

Comment: That looks better than my version, for sure :-).

Comment: the current version is `colortbl.sty    2018/05/02 v1.0c Color table columns (DPC)`, try to update

Comment: Hi, that worked, thanks a ton. Next time I know how to check (via `\listfiles`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved by updating